# iterating over each day in webcalendar-element c#.net asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Yet another webcalendar question...

What I want to do is this:

I have a webcalender. On Each working day, there's a dropdown list with a couple of items to select from (e.g. on holidays, away, blabla...) The person who opens the calendar should see, on each day, the entries he made for that day. If theres a value for that day in the database, the user should see the value from the database. If not, the user should see the the dropdown list.

On a day for which there's no entry in the database, the user should be able to select a value and when he hits "save", the value from the dropdown list should get saved to the database.

My question is how to do this best:
What I guess I have to do is iterate over each day in the celandar and check, if for the date that corresponds to that calendar day, there's and entry in the database. If yes, I display that entry (I know how to insert values from the database into the dropdown list) and if not, i just display the dropwdown list.

So: How can I iterate over each day of the month and compare that day's date to the date in the database?

And: The user should be able to see another person's entries, when selecting that person's name from a menu. So in that case, I would have to access and iterate over each day of the calendar outside of the DayRender-Event, in a separate method.

And if you think I'm thinking way too complicated here, feel free to suggest other ways to do this!

Thanks for your help and tips!

PS. if necessary, I'll post some of my code, of course.

UPDATE
Here's some code to make things clearer (hopefully)

```
DayOfWeek comptag = e.Day.Date.DayOfWeek;
                    string tutu = e.Day.Date.ToString();
                    string ghgh = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Date"].ToString();

                    if (comptag != DayOfWeek.Saturday && comptag != DayOfWeek.Sunday && e.Day.IsOtherMonth == false && ghgh == tutu)
                    {
                        e.Cell.Controls.Add(dropdownlist2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (comptag != DayOfWeek.Saturday && comptag != DayOfWeek.Sunday && e.Day.IsOtherMonth == false)
                        {
                            e.Cell.Controls.Add(dropdownlist);
                        }
                    }
```

So I compare each day of the month with the dates in the database. What I am having trouble with is the iteration: How to I compare for each row in the database if theres a date? Right now, I only get the first row and thus the first date. But if I have 4 dates in the database, I need to compare all four dates. If i write

```
string ghgh = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Date"].ToString();
```

and then put something like i++ for iteration, I get an error after the i-th time that there are no more rows with dates...

Answer (score 0):

I've got it, in case anyone ever needs this. This checks for each calendar day being rendered if there's an entry in the database. It works, but it's certainly not the best solution (cos I'm just not that good).

```
DayOfWeek comptag = e.Day.Date.DayOfWeek;
for (int i = 0; i < ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string thisday = e.Day.Date.ToString();
    string dayfromdb = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Date"].ToString();
    list.Add(dayfromdb);

    if (comptag != DayOfWeek.Saturday && comptag != DayOfWeek.Sunday && e.Day.IsOtherMonth == false && dayfromdb == thisday)
    {
        e.Cell.Controls.Add(auswahlliste2);
    }
    else if (comptag != DayOfWeek.Saturday && comptag != DayOfWeek.Sunday && e.Day.IsOtherMonth == false && liste.Contains(thisday)==false)
    {
        e.Cell.Controls.Add(auswahlliste);
    }
} // Ende for
```